# Dynamically folder creation is not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

Here is my Base controller for upload function

```
protected function upload_data($folder, $name) {
        $config = array(
            'upload_path' => "./upload/".$folder,
            'overwrite' => FALSE,
            'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
            'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)           
            );

        if ($name == "image") {
            $config['allowed_types'] = "gif|jpg|png|jpeg";
            // $config['max_height'] = "450";
            // $config['max_width'] = "400";
        } else if ($name == "video") {
            $config['allowed_types'] = "mp4|webm|mpeg";
            $config['max_size'] = "5120000";
        } else if ($name == "cv_file") {
            $config['allowed_types'] = "pdf|doc|docx";
        }
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload($name)) {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            unset($this->upload);
            return $data;
        } else {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
             unset($this->upload);
            return $error;
        }
    }
```

Below is my controller code to access this upload function

```
public function uploadCheckLists()
    {
        $post_data = $this->input->post();
        $cv_data = $this->upload_data('files', 'cv_file');
        if (isset($cv_data['upload_data'])) {
            $file_path = $cv_data['upload_data']['file_path'];
            $data['cv_name'] = $cv_data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        }
    }
```

This is working fine. But When I want to create user related folder dynamically that folder was creating in root folder and not in the specified path. 
Here is my code to create folder dynamically

```
When I replace this line 
$cv_data = $this->upload_data('files', 'cv_file');
```

with below one it is not working and folder is creating in root folder.

```
$cv_data = $this->upload_data('files/'.mkdir($post_data['selected_user_enc_id']), 'cv_file');

So the folder should create like files/58 (user id)
```

can any one help me in this regard where I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something like `mkdir('files/' . $post_data['selected_user_enc_id']);` before your `$cv_data` line? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: Yes, I tried like below   $folder = base_url().'upload/files/'.$post_data['selected_user_enc_id'];$d =  mkdir($folder);$cv_data = $this->upload_data($d, 'cv_file');

Comment: But nothing happened

Comment: From the [manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php): "_Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure._" So your `$d = mkdir($folder);` will be TRUE or FALSE. Just do `mkdir($folder); $cv_data = $this->upload_data($folder, 'cv_file');`

Comment: Thank you..for this. Your suggestion helps me to solve my issue.

Comment: No problem, glad it works

Answer (score 2):

Must check if not then create folder on you path

```
if (!file_exists('./upload/'.$folder)) {
            mkdir('./upload/'.$folder, 0777, true);
  }
```

You will create folder. It's work on me.

Thank You